# Google Analytics unable to filter for_domain/hostname from traffic on specific set of pages report

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, filtering

I am trying to create a custom report in Google Analytics to see the traffic on a specific set of pages.  Unfortunately for reasons we cannot ascertain, sometimes the hostname is appended like in the example below:

Appended Hostname: `/for_domain/XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/YYYYYYY`

I created the below filter to exclude any hostnames starting with "/for_domain"

```
Exclude   Hostname     REGEX     ^/for_domain
```

But when I run the new report I still see pages with the hostname starting with 
"/for_domain".

Anyone have any idea why that is and how I can exclude pages whose hostnames begin with "/for_domain"?

On a side note, does anyone know how or why our hostnames would be appended with "for_domain"?

Comment: Filters in Google Analtics only affect new data that comes in.   When you say you still see data in the report that should be filtered, are you looking only at dates after which the filter was applied?

Comment: I am not trying to use a filter.  I am trying to make a custom report.  I thought there was a difference. Are they the essentially the same?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after trying a few things, I added a condition to the report which solved the problem.

```
Exclude    Page     REGEX     /for_domain/.*
```

Simply adding the `.*` after the `/for_domain/` eliminates anything that has the `/for_domain/` as the beginning of its page

The below link was where I found the soloution

https://www.lunametrics.com/regex-book/Regular-Expressions-Google-Analytics.pdf