# "/for_domain/" is getting prepended to all URLs in Google Analytics reports

Tags: google-analytics

I have several GA accounts tracking various domains.  For some unknown reason, `/for_domain/` is being added to front of some of my page URLs.  I have tried to exclude them from being reported in the segment I created using multiple logical statements.  None of them worked.

Does anyone have a clue where this `/for_domain/` is, where it is coming from and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Do you have any filters in your GA account?

Comment: This thread may hold the solution, very similar issue: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115663/google-analytics-unable-to-filter-for-domain-hostname-from-traffic-on-specific-s